# Are cats bothered by white noise?

Tags: cats

I'd like to get a cat, but I am concerned about the potential impacts my home environment would have on the cat's wellbeing. I have chronic tinnitus and have white noise pumped throughout my house 24/7 to mask it. I heard that cat's have a stress reaction to hissing sounds, and some forms of white noise sound "hissy" to me, so before I bring a cat into my home, I want to make sure it is going to be a safe and welcoming environment rather than a stressfull, anxiety inducing one.

Do cats react negatively to white noise, and if so, are there some forms that do not bother them (eg a fan whirring vs a thunderstorm vs TV static, etc.)?

Comment: how many DB is your white noise at,there is some background noises in most houses,and most cats have no problem with normal noises like fans and fridges running.

Comment: It's fairly loud: I just measured it at 65dB 1m from the speaker, 45dB on the opposite side of the house, and 30dB in the quietest room.

Comment: 65 DB is the same sound level as on a city street or people talking loud.

Comment: @trondhansen maybe so, but it's the quality of the sound that is the point of the question. There's a big difference to human ears between a loud conversation and a baby crying at the same volume. I'm trying to get at that answer from a cat's perspective.

Comment: Apart from volume, what is very important for cats is they be able to identify the source of the noise, determine it isn't a danger to them, and that it does not mask other sounds that could signal a danger to them.

Comment: thank you for the information,it is important for the one(s) answering your question to know the type and volume of the sound.

Comment: I'll just add here that I use brown noise every night when sleeping and I believe my kitties enjoy it as much as I do